# Creating platform based upon git repo keeps failing

Tags: version-control, aegir

Creating a platform based upon a git repo within Aegir keeps failing. I cloned the repo myself and did a drush make, which succeeded, so I'm not sure what is going wrong.

It keeps failing on:

```
/usr/local/bin/drush --backend=2 @platform_platformsbel provision-verify 2>&1
```

Where I get the following:

```
We could not find an applicable site for that command.  
Drush could not bootstrap this platform. Please check the platform directory exists and is readable.
```

I checked and provision and the platform directory gets created, the git repo gets cloned, but that is as far as it seems to go. I've read all the documentation and used our dear friend Google, but neither is able to help me out.

My setup:

- Ubuntu Server 15.10 x64
- aegir 3.4 (installed from http://debian.aegirproject.org, but moved home directory from /var/aegir/ to /home/aegir/)
- hostmaster-7.x-3.4 (Drupal 7.42)
- drush 8.0.5

Git repo used: https://github.com/belsander/drupal-profile-test3

Could somebody point me in the right direction, please? Thanks!

Full output from hostmaster:

```
Task starts processing: Verify: platformsbel    
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_task_validate  
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_clone_pre_hosting_task   
1 s.
Returned from hook drush_hosting_clone_pre_hosting_task 
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_git_pre_hosting_task 
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_git_pre_hosting_task   
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_migrate_pre_hosting_task 
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_migrate_pre_hosting_task   
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_package_pre_hosting_task 
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_package_pre_hosting_task   
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_site_pre_hosting_task    
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_site_pre_hosting_task  
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_task 
-
Backend invoke: /usr/local/bin/drush --backend=2 --root=/home/aegir/platforms/platformsbel --uri= provision-save '@platform_platformsbel' 2>&1  
-
/usr/local/bin/drush --backend=2 --root=/home/aegir/platforms/platformsbel --uri= provision-save '@platform_platformsbel' 2>&1  
-
Bootstrap to phase 0.   
-
Bootstrap to phase 0.   
-
Found command: provision-save (commandfile=provision)   
-
Loaded alias @server_master from file /home/aegir/.drush/server_master.alias.drushrc.php    
-
Loading mysql driver for the db service 
-
Loading apache driver for the http service  
-
Driver type not specified for the git service, provide it with --git_service_type   
-
Driver type not specified for the db service, provide it with --db_service_type 
-
Driver type not specified for the http service, provide it with --http_service_type 
-
Driver type not specified for the git service, provide it with --git_service_type   
-
Calling hook drush_provision_save   
-
Loaded alias @platform_platformsbel from file /home/aegir/.drush/platform_platformsbel.alias.drushrc.php    
-
Template loaded from Provision Config class Provision_Config_Drushrc_Alias: /usr/share/drush/commands/provision/Provision/Config/Drushrc/provision_drushrc_alias.tpl.php    
-
Changed permissions of /home/aegir/.drush/platform_platformsbel.alias.drushrc.php to 640    
-
Generated config in write(): Drush configuration file (/home/aegir/.drush/platform_platformsbel.alias.drushrc.php)  
-
Changed permissions of /home/aegir/.drush/platform_platformsbel.alias.drushrc.php to 440    
-
Returned from hook drush_provision_save 
-
Command dispatch complete   
1 s.
Scanning into /etc/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ 
-
Scanning into /etc/drush for /platform_platformsbel\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/  
-
Scanning into phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/.. for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/    
-
Scanning into phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/.. for /platform_platformsbel\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ 
-
Scanning into /home/aegir/.drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ 
-
Scanning into /home/aegir/.drush for /platform_platformsbel\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/  
-
Scanning into /home/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.4/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/   
-
Scanning into /home/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.4/drush for /platform_platformsbel\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/    
-
Scanning into /home/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.4/sites/all/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ 
-
Scanning into /home/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.4/sites/all/drush for /platform_platformsbel\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/  
-
Scanning into /home/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.4/sites/aegir.ionica.ca for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/   
-
Scanning into /home/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.4/sites/aegir.ionica.ca for /platform_platformsbel\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/    
1 s.
Scanning into /home/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.4/sites/default for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/   
-
Scanning into /home/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.4/sites/default for /platform_platformsbel\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/    
-
Scanning into /drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ 
-
Scanning into /drush for /platform_platformsbel\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/  
-
Scanning into /sites/all/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/   
-
Scanning into /sites/all/drush for /platform_platformsbel\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/    
-
Scanning into /home/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.4/../drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/    
-
Scanning into /home/aegir/hostmaster-7.x-3.4/../drush for /platform_platformsbel\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ 
-
Loaded alias @platform_platformsbel from file /home/aegir/.drush/platform_platformsbel.alias.drushrc.php    
-
Backend invoke: /usr/local/bin/drush --backend=2 @platform_platformsbel provision-verify 2>&1   
-
/usr/local/bin/drush --backend=2 @platform_platformsbel provision-verify 2>&1   
-
Bootstrap to phase 0.   
-
Bootstrap to phase 0.   
-
Found command: provision-verify (commandfile=provision) 
-
Loaded alias @server_master from file /home/aegir/.drush/server_master.alias.drushrc.php    
-
Loading mysql driver for the db service 
-
Loading apache driver for the http service  
-
Driver type not specified for the git service, provide it with --git_service_type   
-
Including /usr/share/drush/commands/provision/platform/backupmigrate/verify.provision.inc   
-
Including /usr/share/drush/commands/provision/platform/verify.provision.inc 
-
Calling hook drush_provision_drupal_provision_verify_validate   
-
Returned from hook drush_provision_drupal_provision_verify_validate 
-
Calling hook drush_provision_git_provision_verify_validate  
-
Returned from hook drush_provision_git_provision_verify_validate    
-
Calling hook drush_provision_drupal_pre_provision_verify    
1 s.
We could not find an applicable site for that command.  
-
Drush could not bootstrap this platform. Please check the platform directory exists and is readable.    
-
Returned from hook drush_provision_drupal_pre_provision_verify  
-
Command dispatch complete   
1 s.
Returned from hook drush_hosting_task   
-
Invoking hosting_verify_task_rollback hooks.    
-
Changes made in drush_hosting_task have been rolled back.   
-
Command dispatch complete   
-
Updated task status to "Failed"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repository does not contain a Drupal codebase.
The current git integration does expect this.

To use your makefile you can use the 'Deploy from makefile' option and point it at a local path or url.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to try it from the command line if it fails from the UI.

In my case, their API was down:

```
colan@snake[Wed 20 17:47]% git clone git@gitlab.com:group/project.git                                                                                
Cloning into 'project'...
GitLab: API is not accessible
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The other thing to check is that the proper Git modules are enabled at Administration » Hosting » Features.